# Merge the "resize" and "resizing" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I think questions with tag [resize](/questions/tagged/resize) (2,276 questions) should be merged with questions with tag [resizing](/questions/tagged/resizing) (377 questions). Two tags is one too much here. There are no difference (other than semantical). I also noted that 22 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize+resizing) has both tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed: [resizing](/questions/tagged/resizing) --> [resize](/questions/tagged/resize)

Comment: that's great of you man! appriciatons.